# Why do we need the axiom of choice in showing the non-emptiness of an infinite Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Given $I$ a set of indexes and $X_i$ a set of topological spaces, define

> The Cartesian product: $\prod_{i \in I}X_i = \{ f:I \rightarrow \bigcup X_i | f(i) \in X_i \}$

I have read that we need the axiom of choice in order to show that the cartesian product of non-empty collection of non-empty sets is not empty.

**My question is**, why do we need the axiom of choice for that?

If all the spaces are non-empty, pick arbitrarly from each $X_i$ a point $x_i$, and the product is not empty.

I know that this what the axiom of choice is all about. But, The axiom states that we will have a well defined choice function. I don't see where we need a well defined choice function in the case of showing the non-emptyness of an infinite product..

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: "pick arbitrarly" <- That's choice. In fact, the axiom of choice is precisely the assertion that a product of nonempty sets always is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking an arbitrary $x_i$ is exactly where the axiom of choice gets into the picture.

Otherwise, how can you justify the existence of such a function which picks this arbitrary $x_i$?

Recall that the axiom of choice is needed when the product is infinite. When the product is finite, then indeed by induction we can choose an arbitrary $x_i$ and it's fine. But this induction is not transfinite.

Comment: Also, the axiom of _countable_ choice is much weaker than the general axiom of choice. Actually, there's an axiom of choice for each cardinality, but we usually only care about the countable one or the general one.

Comment: This is more complicated than just "each cardinality", we can have several parameters in "axiom of choice for ..." sort of axioms. But I disagree that "we usually only care about the countable one or the general one".

Comment: Didn't Hilbert use the pairs of socks vs pairs of shoes analogy?

Comment: @Henno: Russell. Not Hilbert.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thx. I found it illuminating at the time.

Comment: @Henno: I was never a fan of non-mathematical allusions. I find them temporarily illuminating, but ultimately misleading.

Comment: Well, the general one is clearly the most important and openly discussed variant. The axiom of countable choice is the only other named one. All other would be "axiom of choice for such and such sets". I did go a bit overboard by claiming they are the only ones that are interesting.

Comment: Also, I realise that if we do not assume the general axiom (in which case all of this is a moot point anyways) then there are sets without a well defined cardinality. That there would be other applicable categories on which to assume the axiom is not surprising. I guess the reason I wrote what I wrote was rather to point out that there are weaker variations of AC depending on the size of the product you'd want to be non-empty.

Comment: @Arthur: The fact that countable choice has a name follows from the fact that we have three types of sizes: finite, countable and uncountable. Thank you for the addition pointing that out.

Comment: I see.. will think about in. Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur: [Axiom of global choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice) should also be considered on the spectrum, no?

Comment: Can the countable product of countably infinite sets be empty?

Comment: @Logic Of course.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, but can it be that choice for collection of finite sets fails , but for collection of infinite sets it holds... ? [BTW i think your comment implies that that a countable product of countabley  infinite sets need not have cardinality of R ,right?]

Comment: I feel as if my above question is trivial but, i cant prove it.

Comment: @Logic: No, because if $\prod A_i$ is empty, replace it with $\prod(\Bbb N\times A_i)$, which must also be empty, otherwise we can project on the $A_i$ part in each set and get a choice function from the original collection. To your second question, yes, that is correct. ZF cannot prove that there is a set X such that any countable product of countable sets has cardinality at most X.

Comment: Thank you very much!